# Measure of the Cantor set multiplied by the Cantor set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

It is a quite famous fact that $C+C=[0,2]$, what about $ C \cdot C $ ?

Is it measurable? **Yes**

> It's clearly measurable because it's compact, being a continuous image
>   of the compact set C×C.

Is it possible to list all the intervals of $[0,1]\setminus C\cdot C$ ?

What is its Lebesgue measure ?

Comment: It's clearly measurable because it's compact, being a continuous image of the compact set $C\times C$.

Comment: It looks like an interesting question.  Unless $C\cdot C$ is measure zero or an interval, however, it seems likely there is no simple expression for it.  So first determine whether it is measure zero, or is an interval.

Comment: It can't be an interval because surely $C\cdot C$ doesn't take values in $(\frac{1}{3},\frac{4}{9})$

Comment: Inasmuch as $C\cdot C$ is closed, its complement in $[0,1]$ is the union of countably many disjoint open intervals. One of those intervals is $(\frac13,\frac49)$ as remarked by @Febo; others are $(\frac19,\frac4{27})$ and $(\frac79,\frac{64}{81})$, etc.

Comment: Well, how to find all of them?

Comment: This question and related issues are addressed in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/132445/arithmetic-products-of-cantor-sets. Quote: "It would be interesting to know if A⋅B has positive measure when the sum of the dimensions exceeds 1, but this seems currently out of reach." It look like this is an open and hard question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is already treated in mathoverflow. See [Arithmetic products of Cantor Sets](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132445/arithmetic-products-of-cantor-sets) with interesting, nearly up-to-date information. The question treats self-similar sets on $\mathbb R$ in general. Results with respect to Cantor sets are e.g. that the Hausdorff Dimension $$\dim_H(C\cdot C)  = \min(2 \cdot \dim_H(C),1)=\min\left(2\frac{\ln 2}{\ln 3},1\right) = 1.$$ Another interesting aspect is, that according to the experts there, an answer to the question if $C\cdot C$ has positive measure seems to be out of reach at the time.